# How to count the number of elements in a csv column and return elements in another column based on that count?

Tags: python

I am looking to count the number of times an 'X' appears in the column of a csv file, and based on that I want to return the values of another column if they are in the same row as an 'X'. My csv would look like this:

```
CITIES, PLANE, TRAIN, CAR, BUS
nyc,    X,             X,  X,
hou,           X,      X,
san,    X,     X,
atl,                   X,   X,
den,    X,     X,
```

So for example, if I counted the "X" in the PLANE and the BUS column I would want to return the names nyc, san, den, and atl because they all have an in X in either  column. So far I have imported using pandas, but I also know how to import and convert to a list if that is needed.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data.columns
```

Comment: Have you tried converting to a dictionary? You could use the row names or column names for a key, and then a list of the other names for your values. Should be able to then do a union set on the two lists. In your example, the dict keys would be PLANE, TRAIN, etc. with your CITIES values in the value lists. Then just union the values in PLANE and BUS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas fitering technique:

```
data[(data['PLANE'] == 'X') | (data['BUS'] == 'X')]['CITIES'].tolist()
```

`data['PLANE'] == 'X'` Creates a boolean filter on every row.

`data[data['PLANE'] == 'X']` returns a dataframe with all rows that have an 'X' on the 'PLANE' column.

And then `data[data['PLANE'] == 'X']['CITIES']` returns the CITIES column which you can convert to a list by calling `.tolist()` function.